# /workspace/bot.py:47: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

Tags: loops, warnings

/workspace/bot.py:47: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

Instance is healthy

01:58:01 PM - 1965 - plugins.pm_filter - pm_filter - ERROR - Telegram says: [403 MESSAGE_DELETE_FORBIDDEN] - You don't have rights to delete messages in this chat, most likely because you are not the author of them (caused by "channels.DeleteMessages")

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/workspace/plugins/pm_filter.py", line 1942, in auto_filter

```
await message.delete()
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/types/messages_and_media/message.py", line 3213, in delete

```
return await self._client.delete_messages(
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/messages/delete_messages.py", line 70, in delete_messages

```
r = await self.invoke(
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/invoke.py", line 79, in invoke

```
r = await self.session.invoke(
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 389, in invoke

```
return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 357, in send

```
RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/errors/rpc_error.py", line 91, in raise_it

```
raise getattr(
```

pyrogram.errors.exceptions.forbidden_403.MessageDeleteForbidden: Telegram says: [403 MESSAGE_DELETE_FORBIDDEN] - You don't have rights to delete messages in this chat, most likely because you are not the author of them (caused by "channels.DeleteMessages")

02:11:38 PM - 1965 - plugins.pm_filter - pm_filter - ERROR - Telegram says: [403 MESSAGE_DELETE_FORBIDDEN] - You don't have rights to delete messages in this chat, most likely because you are not the author of them (caused by "channels.DeleteMessages")

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/workspace/plugins/pm_filter.py", line 1942, in auto_filter

```
await message.delete()
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/types/messages_and_media/message.py", line 3213, in delete

```
return await self._client.delete_messages(
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/messages/delete_messages.py", line 70, in delete_messages

```
r = await self.invoke(
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/invoke.py", line 79, in invoke

```
r = await self.session.invoke(
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 389, in invoke

```
return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 357, in send

```
RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/errors/rpc_error.py", line 91, in raise_it

```
raise getattr(
```

pyrogram.errors.exceptions.forbidden_403.MessageDeleteForbidden: Telegram says: [403 MESSAGE_DELETE_FORBIDDEN] - You don't have rights to delete messages in this chat, most likely because you are not the author of them (caused by "channels.DeleteMessages")

02:13:41 PM - 1965 - plugins.pm_filter - pm_filter - ERROR - Telegram says: [403 MESSAGE_DELETE_FORBIDDEN] - You don't have rights to delete messages in this chat, most likely because you are not the author of them (caused by "channels.DeleteMessages")

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/workspace/plugins/pm_filter.py", line 1942, in auto_filter

```
await message.delete()
```

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/types/messages_and_media/message.py", line 3213, in delete

```
return await
```